# Did the Earth have so little oxygen that dinosaurs couldn't exist?

Tags: physiology, climatology, young-earth-creationism

Noted Young-Earth Creationist [Kent Hovind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Hovind) made a claim [in a 2007 video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uX6rM-ayoLw) that suggested that the idea of dinosaurs living on Earth millions of years ago was implauseable if the oxygen levels were the at the same level that exist today.

[TimeStamp from video](http://youtu.be/uX6rM-ayoLw?t=34m3s)

He argued that dinosaurs needed a higher partial pressure of Oxygen to account for their large size ,claiming the partial pressure of Oxygen during the period was too low, that they would not be able to get enough Oxygen. He suggested, in a light-hearted manner, that they would need so much air intake that the very process might have created enough friction to start a fire.

He used this conjecture to demonstrate that the earth might have had a water canopy above it which would increase the partial pressure of oxygen and therefor allow dinosaurs to grow to the sizes that are evident from the fossils. This is based on the [Water Canopy Theory](http://creationwiki.org/Canopy_theory)

Is his conjecture true: Was the partial pressure of Oxygen too low for dinosaurs to exist?

Comment: It's not "common belief" that oxygen made up a greater proportion of the atmosphere during those eras, it's established fact.  During the Jurassic and Cretaceous, and even into the Paleogene and Neogene, oxygen made up a significantly greater proportion of the atmosphere.  During the Jurassic, oxygen made up about 26% of the atmosphere.  During the Cretaceous, it was 30%.

Comment: @Compro01: A claim like that deserves a reference, even in a comment.

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics, @Gerdi. While the claims of Hovind are on-topic (e.g. [1](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/is-the-earth-6000-years-old) and [2](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5993/is-carbon-14-still-increasing-in-the-atmosphere), this question isn't clear. Which specific claim do you want us to tackle: That dinosaurs would need so much air intake they would start a fire (huh?), that the partial pressure of Oxygen was higher and/or lower (when?). That dinosaurs breathed air? That the atmosphere was made of ice? What has any of that to do with Piltdown Man?

Comment: Also, please provide a reference to the videos (the names, a timestamp, a short transcript and perhaps a URL), so we can hear them for ourselves.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that the bulk of what people think of when they say "dinosaur", and certainly the largest of the dinosaurs (the huge sauropods) were not, despite the presupposition of the question, "reptiles"... at least not in the sense of having the characteristics of modern reptile groups. (definition of reptile is "any amniote that is neither a mammal nor a bird"... so "yes", but "no") - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reptiles

Comment: Hi @Oddthinking , sorry for not making it clear. I have edited it. If this still does not conform to the guidelines please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Gerdi: I made some pretty major edits to remove a lot of the side-discussion and focus on the main claim. I would still like a timestamp and a short transcript of the relevant section. There is no way I am listening to two full hours of Hovind; my blood pressure wouldn't allow it.

Comment: @Oddthinking Are you going to take the question 'off hold' now that you have edited it?

Comment: @ChrisW: Whoops! Thanks for pointing out the oversight. Fixed.

Comment: @Gerdi - as OddThinking asked, could you please provide a time stamp, transcript, and other details on the video?  Those of us in the US are constitutionally protected from cruel and unusual punishment, so we shouldn't have to to sit through two hours of a Kent Hovind video.  As far as atmospheric oxygen concentrations go, Compro01 appears to be right - the oxygen concentration was higher, not lower, during the Cretaceous period when the dinosaurs lived (http://geology.com/usgs/amber/).

Comment: @Mark: I know less than the average 8-year-old about the order of the periods, and which dinosaurs were around when. How should I resolve your reference about high oxygen concentration in the Cretaceous and ChrisW's answer about low oxygen levels 275 million to 175 million years ago?

Comment: Thanks @Oddthinking . I will def try to make my questions more concise. I will also look for a transcript otherwise ill just watch it again and find the quote.

Comment: I've rolled back the question so the title is again correct, removed comments relative to the new title and reopened. Please be careful when editing not to change/distort the claim in ...question.

Comment: Also, please don't change existing, answered (accepted!) questions (unless for substantiative grammar edits or broken links). In general, it seems like the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Sklivvz Hey .. I am not going to bother editing anything, because i feel i already have a good answer. But the title is not part of the claim. There is no claim in the video or the canopy theory that suggests Dinosaurs never existed. I am not sure if you have watched the video or not but , I think, this title is misleading to the main context of the question.

Comment: It's easier to just bear in mind that Hovind is incorrect on pretty much everything he's ever said, to the point that if he tells you he's certain the sky is blue it's wise to check outside for confirmation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following articles suggest that dinosaurs breathed efficiently, like birds do still: which allowed them to cope with low oxygen levels that killed off other species.
Note that [some birds are able to breathe and fly at 20,000 feet](http://www.webcitation.org/6ESilGnVV), where the oxygen is lower ([less than half sea-level pressure](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1114067/figure/FN0x97c9610.0x9bb8c18/)).

---

[BBC Earth - Did all dinosaurs breathe like birds?](http://www.walkingwithdinosaurs.com/news/post/did-all-dinosaurs-breathe-like-birds/)

> BIRDS EVOLVED from carnivorous theropod dinosaurs.
>
> Living birds have a very unusual system of respiration, which sets
>   them apart from all other animals: their lungs are unidirectional.
>
> In birds, the unidirectional nature of the lung means that air with
>   oxygen passes through the lungs during inhalation and exhalation.
>
> Birds can do this because they have a system of air sacs that connect
>   to the lungs, which store air during the entire breathing cycle.
>   During inhalation, oxygen-rich air passes through the lungs directly
>   from the trachea, but during exhalation other oxygen-rich air that had
>   been stored in air sacs passes across the lungs.
>
> Their lung is remarkably efficient at getting lots of oxygen into the
>   blood. This is important because birds fly, and flight is an activity
>   that requires a lot of energy and an elevated metabolism, both of
>   which require a large quantity of oxygen.
>
> So did dinosaurs have this type of lung? Some dinosaurs definitely
>   did. We know that because the air sacs often leave characteristic
>   traces on the bones, which fossilise.
>
> In many birds and dinosaurs the air sacs are actually inside the bones
>   themselves, hollowing out the centre. We can see these internal
>   sinuses, as well as the circular or oval-shaped openings that lead
>   into them, in many bones of theropod and sauropod dinosaurs. This is
>   clear evidence that they had a bird-like lung.
>
> We are not so sure about ornithischians, such as the horned dinosaurs
>   and duck-billed dinosaurs. Their bones do not have the hollow centres
>   and circular or ovoid ‘foramina’ that are so often seen in the bones
>   of theropods and sauropods. This may mean that ornithischians breathed
>   very differently compared to other dinosaurs.
>
> This is an important question about dinosaur biology that is currently
>   the subject of much research by palaeontologists, so keep your eyes
>   peeled!

[ABC Science - Did low oxygen give dinosaurs a boost?](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2003/11/03/980837.htm)

> Low oxygen levels could have triggered two giant extinctions hundreds
>   of millions of years ago, allowing the dinosaurs to reign supreme over
>   the ancestors of mammals, a U.S. researcher says.
>
> University of Washington palaeontologist, Dr Peter Ward, presents his
>   argument to a meeting of the Geological Society of America in Seattle,
>   Washington this week.
>
> Dinosaurs first appeared during a long period of low oxygen and
>   therefore developed highly efficient breathing mechanisms that allowed
>   them to thrive while many other species became extinct. Ward arrived
>   at his theory by tying in what is known about the physiology of
>   dinosaurs with recent geological evidence suggesting that from 275
>   million to 175 million years ago, oxygen levels stayed very low -
>   comparable to levels found now at altitudes of 4,200 metres.
>
> Ward believes low oxygen and hot greenhouse conditions caused by
>   intense volcanic activity may have caused widespread extinctions 250
>   million years ago, at the boundary between the Permian and Triassic
>   periods, and about 200 million years ago, at the boundary between the
>   Triassic and Jurassic periods.
>
> Ward said he put together three pieces of the puzzle - the extremely
>   efficient breathing systems of birds, the finding that many dinosaurs
>   had similar physiology, and a report that came out earlier this year
>   showing that oxygen levels were low during the two extinctions.
>
> "Someone told me they had heard of or seen geese flying above [Mount]
>   Everest - at 31,000 feet [10,000 metres]," said Ward, pointing out the
>   air at this altitude was very thin. "If you put a human at 30,000 feet
>   they'd be very, very, quite dead. And the birds are not only up there,
>   they are doing major heavy exercise."
>
> Birds and dinosaurs both have holes in their bones. And many of the
>   largest dinosaurs, such as brontosaurus or apatosaurus, seem to have
>   had lungs attached to a series of thin-walled air sacs that may have
>   acted something like bellows to move air through the body.
>
> "The reason the birds developed these systems is that they arose from
>   dinosaurs halfway through the Jurassic Period. They are how the
>   dinosaurs survived," Ward said. "The literature always said that the
>   reason birds had sacs was so they could breathe when they fly. But I
>   don't know of any brontosaurus that could fly."
>
> "However, when we considered that birds fly at altitudes where oxygen
>   is significantly lower, we finally put it all together with the fact
>   that the oxygen level at the surface was only 10% to 11% at the time
>   the dinosaurs evolved." Currently at sea level, atmospheric oxygen
>   levels are 21%.
>
> If giant dinosaurs had to breathe in a low-atmosphere environment,
>   then such an efficient breathing system would have given them a
>   survival advantage.
>
> "You'd be really favoured for survival in very bad, nasty, low-oxygen
>   world," Ward said.

Comment: I edited (removed text from) the above articles slightly when I quoted them, but what I quoted is more than half of each article.

Comment: The claim of very low O2 from 275 to 175 million years ago seems at variance with the more recent paper mentioned in my (updated) answer, see Figure 1 (d) http://www.nature.com/ngeo/journal/v3/n9/fig_tab/ngeo923_F1.html .  However, I suspect proxy reconstructions going back that far are rather likely to be uncertain.

Comment: "In many birds and dinosaurs the air sacs are actually inside the bones themselves" .. oh that is cool!! Thanks man . cool answer

Comment: According to Fastovsky & Weishampel, "Dinosaurs - A Concise Natural History" (2nd edition), CUP, the unidirectional breathing was an adaptation that allowed long necks.  With bidirectional breathing the air in the trachea at the end of the inhalation is wasted and must be pushed out before air can be exhaled from the lungs.  Presumably the return route rejoined the trachea near the head so this dead space is eliminated.  The book doesn't seem to mention low oxygen, so presumably thought on this may have moved on, very interesting though!

Answer (score 6):

The [blue whale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_whale) is a [larger animal than any dinosaur](http://www.fao.org/fishery/species/2744/en) with similarly large nostrils (see below) and is also warm blooded.  It seems to be able to breathe without any problems (including spontaneous combustion ;o), in an atmosphere with lower oxygen levels than in the Cretateous (see below), which suggests there isn't really any need for higher partial pressure of oxygen.

Regarding atmospheric oxygen during the Phanerozoic era, [this paper](http://www.nature.com/ngeo/journal/v3/n9/full/ngeo923.html) looks interesting [**emphasi**s mine]

> Ian J. Glasspool & Andrew C. Scott, Phanerozoic concentrations of atmospheric 
>   oxygen reconstructed from sedimentary charcoal, Nature Geoscience 3, 627 - 
>   630 (2010)
>
> Abstract
>
> Variations of the Earth’s atmospheric oxygen concentration (pO2) are
>   thought to be closely tied to the evolution of life, with strong
>   feedbacks between uni- and multicellular life and oxygen1, 2. On the
>   geologic timescale, pO2 is regulated by the burial of organic carbon
>   and sulphur, as well as by weathering3. Reconstructions of atmospheric
>   O2 for the past 400 million years have therefore been based on
>   geochemical models of carbon and sulphur cycling4, 5, 6. However,
>   these reconstructions vary widely4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, particularly
>   for the Mesozoic and early Cenozoic eras. Here we show that the
>   abundance of charcoal in mire settings is controlled by pO2, and use
>   this proxy to reconstruct the concentration of atmospheric oxygen for
>   the past 400 million years. We estimate that pO2 was continuously
>   above 26% during the Carboniferous and Permian periods, and that it
>   declined abruptly around the time of the Permian–Triassic mass
>   extinction. During the Triassic and Jurassic periods, pO2 fluctuated
>   cyclically, with amplitudes up to 10% and a frequency of 20–30 million
>   years. Atmospheric oxygen concentrations have declined steadily from
>   the middle of the Cretaceous period to present-day values of about
>   21%. **We conclude, however, that variation in pO2 was not the main
>   driver of the loss of faunal diversity during the Permo–Triassic and
>   Triassic–Jurassic mass extinction events.**

Dinosaurs evolved in the Triassic and persisted through the Jurassic and Cretateous, and it seems that Oxygen levels have fluctuated considerably during the time, but for the most part were higher than they are now.  If lung efficiency was the issue that caused the dominance of the dinosaurs it seems odd that this continued through the Cretaceous where oxygen levels were apparently generally higher than they are now (why didn't any other groups evolve similar compensatory mechanisms given the long timescale available).  However, this is only one study, and I am no expert on this topic.

Also, from what I remember large dinosaurs developed largely from the mid-Jurassic to Cretaceous.

Lastly, having seen some of the video, the claim is that Apatosaurus had nostrils the size of a horse.  According to Weischampel, Dodson and Osmolska, "Dinosauria", page 273 "In general terms, the most striking features of the sauropod skull include the enlarged and retracted externel nares [DM: nostrils]".  See also

> Lawrence M. Witmer "Nostril position in dinosaurs and other
>   vertebrates and its significance for nasal function", Science 3 August
>   2001: Vol. 293 no. 5531 pp. 850-853 [DOI:10.1126/science.1062681](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1062681)
>
> **Many dinosaurs have enormous and complicated bony nasal apertures**. Functional interpretation requires knowledge of the location of the
>   external opening in the skin. Traditionally, the fleshy nostril of
>   dinosaurs has been placed in the back of the bony opening, but studies
>   of extant dinosaur relatives suggest that it is located far forward.
>   Narial blood supply and cavernous tissue corroborate the rostral
>   position in dinosaurs. A rostral nostril was, and remains, a virtually
>   invariant rule of construction among Amniota, which has consequences
>   for (i) nasal airstreaming, and hence various physiological
>   parameters, and (ii) the collection of behaviorally relevant
>   circumoral odorants.

Note that as soft tissue rarely gets significantly fossilised, the "enormous and complicated bony nasal apertures" are pretty much all we have to go on, so I suspect Hovind's comment about the size of their nostrils is at best a guess.  Clearly if the dinosaurs needed bigger fleshy nostrils, their skulls could have accommodated them.

See also CrisW's answer for another possible explanation.

Comment: it does have a lung capacity of 5000 liters to help with that

Comment: Dinosaurs had rather large rib cages as well, at the London science museum they have skeletons of both (though not in the same room) for comparison.

Comment: Are you sure that's the Science Museum? The Natural History Museum just down the road seems more likely.

Comment: yes, you are of course quite right, I was there only a couple of months ago as well - doh!  Well worth a visit though.

Comment: Hey @DikranMarsupial Yeah it actually makes sense that it is so large considering that it breaths oxygen. The pressure depth at which it mainly lives makes the oxygen in its blood a very high partial pressure according to Boyle's law.

Comment: so why the downvote?

Comment: I didnt down vote .. i dont think i can .. not enough points

Comment: Sorry gerdi, I didn't mean it as a comment on your comment, just a request for whoever down-voted to explain why.  I am always happy to update my answers if there is a valid criticism.  Being wrong and not knowing why makes it difficult to learn from mistakes!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I wonder how the existence of Blue Whales in the modern era (with, allegedly, high-oxygen atmosphere and large "nostrils") has any bearing on whether dinosaurs were larger than physically possible in the Permian–Triassic era.

Comment: As my answer shows, dinosaurs also had large nostrils and oxygen arguably isn't higher now than it was in the Cretateous and most of the Jurassic (see Figure 1 of the Glasspool and Scott paper).  The blue whale part of the answer was from the initial version of the question, which appears to have drifted quite substantially.  The fact that an animal exists today (with lower oxygen than the Cretateous) suggests that this wasn't a bar to th evolution of large dinosaurs.  ChisW's answer is still interesting, in science there is often more than one explanation of anything.

Comment: I don't have the dinosaur book I want in my office, but IIRC dinosaurs didn't exist in the Permian and only became very large in the mid-late Jurassic and Cretateous when oxygen levels were apparently higher.

Comment: I downvoted a much shorter version of this answer, which I wasn't happy about. I'll retract it now.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it was the feedback that was important rather than the downvote.