# What was the density of prehistoric Earth atmosphere (dinosaurs buoyancy theory)

Tags: geology, earth, air

There is a site by David Esker named Dinosaur Theory: [dinosaurtheory.com](http://www.dinosaurtheory.com). David says that dinosaurs was so big because the early (at dinosaurs age) earth atmosphere was very dense and most mass of extinct giant reptilians and other non-avian dinosaurs was compensated by [Buoyancy force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy) from air.

http://www.dinosaurtheory.com/solution.html

> the Earth's atmospheric density during the late Jurassic period can be calculated to be 670 kg/m<sup>3</sup>. This says that to produce the necessary buoyancy so that the dinosaurs could grow to their exceptional size, the density of the Earth’s air near the Earth’s surface would need to be 2/3’s of the density of water.

And he says that now at sea level "*air has a low density of only 1.29 kg/m<sup>3</sup>*". Thanks to Dikran Marsupial, 670 kg/m<sup>3</sup> is very high, like density of some light wood types.

I have some doubts about so dense (thick) atmosphere and my question is: Is there any scientific evidence of Earth's atmosphere density in the era of dinosaurs?

Comment: Related Question: [Did the Earth have so little Oxygen that dinosaurs couldn't exist](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/did-the-earth-have-so-little-oxygen-that-dinosaurs-couldnt-exist).

Comment: Oddthinking, yes the question is related, but different. He asks about O2 partial pressure, and I asks about total air pressure.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean it was a duplicate. Just 'if you are interested in this proposed solution to the "dinosaur problem", you may also like...'.

Comment: I'd love to see an extension of this theory: that the atmosphere was so dense that dinosaurs could float like blimps! Then, I'd love to see it made into a movie :-)

Comment: One should probably look at all the stuff in that time that could fly and e.g. their wing sizes. If a pterodactyl needed almost a meter of wing size, either it must have been very heavy, or evolution must have been extraordinarily generous to provide it with so much more than needed for that "air" density

Answer (score 11):

Esker has no evidence to support the idea of the Earths atmosphere being more dense in the Jurrasic than it is now, other than the assertion that dinosaurs are too large to have existed otherwise.  However this assertion has little support, as evolutionary adaptions (such as the unidirectional breathing discussed in the previous question) are able to explain the size of giant hebivorous dinosaurs seen in the Jurassic, without the need to introduce bouyancy from a dense atmosphere.  Resource availability seems to be more of a limiting factor on size than gravitational issues.

See e.g. Saunders et al. "Biology of the sauropod dinosaurs: the evolution of gigantism" Biol Rev Camb Philos Soc. 2011 February; 86(1): 117–155. [www](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3045712/)

Also, allometry suggests that the ratio of the long bone dimensions and plausible body weight of dinosaurs is similar to that of modern animals.

P.S. you do have to wonder about anybody that refers to themselves in the third person ["Esker’s Thick Atmosphere Theory violates no property of science. It is the correct solution."](http://www.dinosaurtheory.com/solution.html) in supposedly scientific writing! ;o)

Comment: Dikran, thanks, but I think about some independent paleontology evidence of early atmosphere pressure. There are air bubbles frozen in the ice, there can be bubbles tapped in lava, etc..

Comment: Hmm, this not only Esker to believe in more dense atmosphere in epoch of dyno: http://pubs.acs.org/subscribe/archive/ci/30/i12/html/12learn.html

Comment: The ACS article seems to be referring to large flying animals, rather than the giant herbivores that Esker is talking about.  You would need far higher pressures to achieve substantial bouyancy than would be necessary for aerodynamics.  A change of 4-5bar is not going to result in over two orders of magnitude difference in air density.

Comment: There isn't any ice on the planet nearly old enough to hold air from the Jurassic, and the gasses in lava are dissolved gasses that come from inside the mantle, not from the atmosphere.

Comment: Lava may record atmosphere too: "Vesicular lavas preserve a record of paleopressure at the time and place of lava emplacement" http://geology.gsapubs.org/content/30/9/807.abstract http://www.geo.mtu.edu/~raman/papers2/SahagianJG.pdf

Comment: Very interesting, I stand corrected; of course the air in the lava bubbles isn't atmospheric, but the size of the bubbles would depend on ambient pressures.

Comment: Incidentally, to put things into context, 670 kg/m3 is about the density of cuban mahogany (http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-density-d_40.html).

Comment: Thinking about this, volcanic pummice has a density of about 640 kg/m3, so if Jurassic air density was 670 kg/m3, then pumice would float... in the air!  As would a lot of vegetable matter, such as any wood less dense than mahogany, which rather suggests that Jurassic air density was perhaps unlikely to have been that high! ;o)

Comment: “This theory violates no scientific law (that I can think of), therefore it is correct." o.O

Comment: Dikran, there is new article http://www.nature.com/ngeo/journal/v9/n6/full/ngeo2713.html "Earth's air pressure 2.7 billion years ago constrained to less than half of modern levels" - Nature Geoscience 9, 448–451 (2016)  doi:10.1038/ngeo2713. They did it with bubble's size: "... we calculate absolute Archaean barometric pressure using the **size distribution of gas bubbles in basaltic lava** flows that solidified at sea level ~2.7 Gyr"!

Answer (score 9):

The claimed air density is about 520 times higher than air denisty now. This means that, according to the [ideal gas law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law), you need 520 times the air pressure - roughly 520 bar.

Now the [critical point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28thermodynamics%29) of [nitrogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen) (main consituent of air) is about 33bar, the critical point of [oxygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen) about 50 bar. Both critical temperatures are far below 0°C. So at this density, the athmosphere would be a [supercritical fluids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid). Most importantly that means:

> It can effuse through solids like a gas, and dissolve materials like a liquid.

So, to sum it up, with a little bit of knowledge about physics we can show that gases behave radically different before we are close to the pressures described. Whoever claimed an athmospheric density of 670kg/m³ did not think the physics side through.

Comment: Thank you mart! [Venus has supercritical atmosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid#Planetary_atmospheres) ("93 bar... 735 K ... making the surface atmosphere a supercritical fluid") without any visible side-effects: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRGTk0KQhf4 Are there scientific papers saying that Earth atmosphere was not supercritical fluid 300-50 Ma ago?

Comment: @osgx Are there any scientific papers that say that Earths atmosphere was NOT a supercritical fluid?

You mean aside from the full body of physics as it currently exists?

Science assumes something is NOT the case unless you have evidence that shows otherwise. Since there is no science that shows that the atmosphere WAS supercritical fluids, we don't ASSUME it was.

Comment: @osgx Actually, it is science fact that Earths atmospher was exactly like Venus. It was a 90+bar and 98% Co2. Where do you think all the Carboniferous rocks came from?. The Co2 has been sucked out of the atmosphere by orgasims and locked up in rocks, so the pressure has been dropping continuously over time. Atmospheric Co2 is currently the lowest it has ever been in geological history. If it reduces much more, plants will not be able to photosynthesis.

Comment: @Andyk, Welcome to the skeptics. Unreferenced claims requires scientific (published in peer-reviewed and cited) references here. When this 90+bar was, was it in the "late Jurassic period" (as in question) or earlier or later? Unscientific wiki claims that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous period had ONLY "Mean atmospheric CO2 ... **c. 800 ppm**", not anywhere near even 1% (nor 98%). And just think about how carbon-fixating organism may live on the planet with the supercritical atmosphere; and how it is possible to have "like Venus" atmospheric temperatures and Earth life at same time

Comment: I certainly tread in caution here, perhaps I'm missing something, but since $P={rho}RT\M$, shouldn't a density increase be balanceable not just by P increase (as noted)... but also a T decrease or an M increase?? So it wouldn't be a straight 520 bars per se.

Comment: But indeed, there shouldn't be a huge proportion T decrease... and unlikely to have many times the molar mass of air now (https://www.britannica.com/topic/evolution-of-the-atmosphere-1703862 would suggest more CO2 might up the molar mass some... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth suggests that on even earlier Earth it was very very light).  But the two factors of T and M could reasonably perhaps drop the P increase needed it to be like 200-400 bars.  Not changing things a ton, but just something that seemed to be rushed past :-)